# Is it possible to control keyboard back-lights in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, hardware

So I have a custom build laptop with only Ubuntu installed.

During boot-up, the back-lighting for the keyboard comes alive, and shows off the various changing colours it is capable.

[image: keyboard1]
[image: keyboard2]

I cannot find any way to control or engage with this hardware feature once Ubuntu has loaded.

There are keys on the number pad which appear to be marked with symbols related to back-lighting, but I've never had them work.

[image: number pad]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does the keyboard itself have a button to control this? I have a HP Envy and my F5 buttons has that fuction ( not pressing the fn-key ). Because of the angle it is not clear to me if your keyboard has such a function.

Comment: @JoepieEs  I've added a photo of keys which look like they might be back-lighting related.  (Wishing I'd given keyboard a quick clean!)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with Ubuntu itself but with bios/uefi and the kernel. The main 2 possible methods seem to work with different brands, make, and models.

First method change:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

and alter:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_os_name=Linux acpi_osi=! 
acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and

```
sudo update-grub
```

Second method: There is also a module made by Tuxedo Computers that could work (Tuxedo own computers, Tensorbook, Sager; all of these are also custom notebooks). See https://github.com/tuxedocomputers/tuxedo-keyboard for details.

Basically it comes to this. If you do not have dkms first do ...

```
sudo apt install dkms
```

and ...

```
git clone https://github.com/tuxedocomputers/tuxedo-keyboard
cd tuxedo-keyboard
make && sudo make dkmsinstall
sudo modprobe tuxedo_keyboard
```

- Do not use both at the same time.
- If any of the 2 works it should activate: Fn /, Fn *, Fn -, Fn +
- If it does not please comment and I will remove it, or try to find another method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried adding `acpi_os_name=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` to the Grub default, based on answers found after googleing "acpi" from your answer. I wasn't sure what the `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=Linux` part was (and where the whitespace goes) as I didn't see it elsewhere. It didn't get a result for my particular laptop.

Comment: Based on this answer, the Function keys for the backlight don't generate events https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316600/cant-get-my-brightness-fn-keys-working-on-asus-n551vw

Comment: This answer explained what the `!` part was for ...
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246672/how-to-set-acpi-osi-parameter-in-the-grub